# How do I replace a substring that appears more than once in a string using a while loop?

Tags: c#

I have a string that contains the same two substrings that I need to find and replace.

I used the `Contains()` method which works fine if there is only one occurrence of the substring.

```
string test = "abc";

if (line.Contains(test))
{
    string newLine = line;

    while (line.Contains(test))
    { 
        newLine = newLine.Replace(test, "Hello");
    }
}
```

I basically need something that can break me out of the loop. Such as nextMatch in regex.

Comment: Change `while (line.Contains(test))` to `while (newLine.Contains(test))`.

Answer (score 5):

Unless I have misunderstood, you are trying to replace all instances of test in line?
Just do this:

```
line = line.Replace(test, "Hello")
```

no while or loop needed.